# saving rotated Bitmap android

Tags: android, bitmap, camera, android-intent, rotation

(Forgive me if Im getting this totally wrong, I am a newbie)
I am displaying some photos taken with `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. I tried to disable autoorientation when picture is being taken but it doesnt seem to work, i used

```
putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION,ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR)
```

This forced me to rotate some of the taken photos. I then save these photos to SDCARD. My problem is that i dont want to rotate them every time user loads a photo. I tried this code to create a new Bitmap that would be saved in 'rotated' state. It worked on emulator but crashes on my HTC. I assume its a memory problem. Is there any way to do this efficiently? Better yet, is there any way to really disable autoorientation while taking photos with Camera Intent?

```
tempBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(dirPath+filename+".jpg");
int tempW = tempBitmap.getWidth();
int tempH = tempBitmap.getHeight();

if (tempW>tempH) {
     Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
     mtx.postRotate(90);
     Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.createBitmap(tempBitmap, 0, 0, 
                                                         tempW, tempH, mtx, true));

} else{
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Same as above but he forgot some code on the last line

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 4; //1/4 of the original image

tempBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(dirPath+filename+".jpg", options);
int tempW = tempBitmap.getWidth();
int tempH = tempBitmap.getHeight();

if (tempW>tempH) {
Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
mtx.postRotate(90);
Bitmap rotatedBitmap = **Bitmap.createBitmap**(tempBitmap, 0,0,tempW, tempH, mtx, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

try reducing the image that you are working with it may be a memory issue.  See below for possible solution.

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 4; //1/4 of the original image

tempBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(dirPath+filename+".jpg", options);
int tempW = tempBitmap.getWidth();
int tempH = tempBitmap.getHeight();

if (tempW>tempH) {
    Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
    mtx.postRotate(90);
    Bitmap rotatedBitmap = (tempBitmap, 0,0,tempW, tempH, mtx, true);
```

Comment: It might be good to point out why you think reducing the image is an option.

Answer (score 0):

Go through following code,

For Stop ratation of image use following code -

```
private int getImageOrientation() 
{
    final String[] imageColumns = {MediaStore.Images.Media._ID, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION};
    final String imageOrderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " DESC";
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            imageColumns, null, null, imageOrderBy);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int orientation = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION));
        System.out.println("orientation===" + orientation);
        cursor.close();
        return orientation;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

If you are facing any issue please refer following link

http://androidlift.info/2016/01/07/android-camera-image-capturing-and-uploading-to-php-server/